# Allow Users with Low Rep to Edit their own Questions Without Removing any Images

Tags: feature-request, editing, questions, images

The only question I have so far asked really required an image to illustrate the point. Another user with sufficient rep kindly added the image to the original question with an edit. I now have further info to provide but I cannot edit the original question without losing the image that was so kindly attached for me.

I have compromised by adding the extra detail in a comment but this is not very satisfactory as it is easy to skim over the comments.

It would be much better if the an image, once included in a question, was allowed to remain when a question is edited by a low-rep bum like myself, providing (of course) its url is unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

The threshold for adding images is very low (11, I think) and that as a community we're really quite good about voting up decent questions — which means that this is a pretty small corner case. (I'm pretty sure you *can* edit the original and keep the picture now, in your specific example.)

Meanwhile, the code to do this correctly and handle all the corner cases isn't completely trivial, so the feature wouldn't come for free. If it can be handled nicely by something clever on the backend, cool, but if it would be significant work, I don't think it this should be prioritized very highly.

Comment: I would agree with all of that. It's just one of those things that removes a small amount of polish from the overall feeling of quality on the site.